# How to get a list of broken links using Powershell? for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, sharepoint-server

I need a SharePoint 2010 Management Shell script that is going to generate a csv file with a list of broken links in one of my site collection and its sub sites. The script should support powershell version 2.0

I have no experience in writing PS scripts. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use SharePoint Broken Link Manager, it was written specifically for SharePoint broken links http://www.qipoint.com

Answer (score 9):

Here's a PowerShell function that returns a hash table with all links on a page at a given URL and their status codes:

```
Function Get-LinksWithStatusCode
(
    [string] $Url
)
{
    $links = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url).Links | Select -ExpandProperty href -Unique
    $hash = @{}

    foreach ($link in $links)
    {
        Try
        {
            $statusCode = Invoke-WebRequest -Url $link -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select -ExpandProperty StatusCode
        }
        Catch
        {
            $_
            $statusCode = $_
        }

        $hash.Add($link, $statusCode)       
    }
}
```

I reappropriated a lot of the code from [this](http://www.zerrouki.com/check-brokenlinks/) link; it requires PowerShell v3.0.  If you cannot use v3, you can use `[System.Net.WebClient]`.

Also, I didn't filter out the links section to only `http://*` like the blog author did.  If you do this, you lose all internal links in SharePoint.  I'm not sure you can execute those `Invoke-WebRequest`s, so you may need to append your `SPWeb.Url` onto those.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like what I need. How do I write the results to a .csv file? Thanks

Comment: Sorry that I didn't see your comment sooner.  To write the results to a csv, try this `$hash | Export-Csv "filename.csv"`

Comment: how do we use this code in powershell v2.0?

Comment: Instead of $statusCode = $_ you should be using $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__ -- that way all of the values are the actual response codes (I'd also suggest not echoing out the exception as it is pretty pointless, since you are adding them all to the list).

Comment: I think you're right in both counts.  I was outputting the error itself because I didn't want to just swallow them.  However, if used in production, you would both want to not echo it out, but also echo out `$hash`, as I don't think it's actually returned in this function.

Comment: I tried to add both (as well as the typo with URL instead of Uri), but my edit was rejected: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/45690

Comment: @jmoreno There may be a difference with later versions of PowerShell. I also used -Uri e.g.  `$statuscode = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $link -Credential $cred -MaximumRedirection 0 | select -ExcludeProperty StatusCode`

Comment: @Underverse: the second Invoke-WebRequest uses "-Url" instead of "-Uri" -- a typo.

Comment: Rejected on the grounds that part of the answer was changed in the Catch section. I'd suggest editing again, just to fix the Url / Uri mistake as this kind of thing is highly annoying to newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need PowerShell for that?

Just use any tool for identifying broken links, such as [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://xenus-link-sleuth.en.softonic.com/)

You don't need to run from the server either, plus it provides more information and a GUI.

Of course you can search for other similar tools if this is not the best choice for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Would this work for password protected pages as well?

Comment: Such tools accept in many cases credentials. You have to check though.

Comment: Some sites disallow third party software which means that using utilities like this not an option

Comment: The benefit of using PowerShell is you're not introducing a 3rd party program into the environment and thus no change to the security posture.