# SP13: Broken Link Scan

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, site-collection, hyperlink

I dont want to go from page to page to manual search for broken links.

Intent: To scan site collection for broken links. 
In SharePoint 2017 you use designer and pull up the reports to view broken links.  In SharePoint 2010 you can access the site directory to complete the scan.

Question:  How would do a broken link scan in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were in the same boats and end up with buying the 3rd party tools(QIpoint Link checker). this worked for us.they offer a trial version so you can try it.

[Broken Link Manager](http://www.qipoint.com/broken_link_manager?catId=70)

Also check this one, he mentioned some powershell for SharePoint 2010 may be work for 2013.

[How to get a list of broken links using Powershell? for Sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109005/how-to-get-a-list-of-broken-links-using-powershell-for-sharepoint-2010)